# highlight a text word by word (jquery) (closed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want create an effect of highlighting to read a text. For example i want highlight this text:

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum  <i>is simply dummy</i> text of the printing and typesetting industry</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of <u><b>the printing and</b></u> typesetting industry</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is <b>simply dummy</b> text of the printing and typesetting industry</p>
</div>
```

For the moment I found this function but it does not preserve the tags:

```
var text = $('div').text();
var regex = text.split(' ');
$('div').html('');
for (i = 0, len = regex.length; i < len; i++) {
    $('div').append('<span>' + regex[i] + ' </span>');
}
$('#click').click(function() {
j = 0;
var t = setInterval(
    function() {
        $('span').eq(j).addClass('highlight');
        j++;
    }, 500
 );
});
```

I think is possible with regular expression for example: `/(<[^>]+>)?([^<]*)/g`

To capture the tags and put them in a table to read this table after but I do not know how do this. For the moment my result can be seen here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzWMe/11/)

My while loop won't stop. So stop the script. Thanks!

---

I found what I wanted : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzWMe/39/)

```
var pattern = /(<[^>]+>)?([^<]*)?/g
var text = $('div').html();
array = new Array();
while ((result = pattern.exec(text)) && (result[0].length) > 0) {
    array.push(result[1]);
    if (typeof result[2] !== 'undefined' && result[2].trim().length > 0) {
        var textSplit = result[2].split(' ');
        for (i = 0, len = textSplit.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (textSplit[i].length > 0) {
                array.push('<span>' + textSplit[i] + '</span>')
            }
        }
    }
    var i = 0;
};
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML = array.join(" ");
$('#click').click(function () {
    j = 0;
    var t = setInterval(
    function () {
        $('span').removeClass('highlight');
        $('span').eq(j).addClass('highlight');
        j++;
        if (j >= $('span').length) {
            clearInterval(t);
        } 
    }, 500);
});
```

thank you for your help Nelson

Answer (score 1):

Cancel the interval when it reaches the total number of span , like this:

```
var t = setInterval(
    function() {
        $('span').eq(j).addClass('highlight');
        j++;
        if (j >= $('span').length ) {
           clearInterval(t);
        }
    }, 500
 );
```

See [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/ZPRNV/)

Comment: the tags of my text is not keep. I want this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/uVnP7.png

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you, can you rephrase it?

Comment: I want to keep the carriage return